# Custom Range of dates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of dates which look like this, it's a list of dates.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2021-07-05
    [1] => 2021-07-06
    [2] => 2021-07-07
    [3] => 2021-07-08
    [4] => 2021-07-09
    [5] => 2021-07-10
    [6] => 2021-07-11
    [7] => 2021-07-12
    [8] => 2021-07-13
    [9] => 2021-07-14
    [10] => 2021-07-15
    [11] => 2021-07-16
    [12] => 2021-07-17
    [13] => 2021-07-18
    [14] => 2021-07-19
    [15] => 2021-07-20
    [16] => 2021-07-21
    [17] => 2021-07-22
)
```

How can i get the below date ranges? Every 6 dates, because i need to loop after in a specific way.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2021-07-05
            [to] => 2021-07-11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2021-07-11
            [to] => 2021-07-17
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 2021-07-17
            [to] => 2021-07-22
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this example.

```
$from = $dates[0];
$to = $from;
$result = [];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    if (strtotime($from) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 6 < strtotime($date)) {
        $result[] = ['from' => $from, 'to' => $to];
        $from = $to;
    }
    $to = $date;
}
$result[] = ['from' => $from, 'to' => $to];

print_r($result);
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/ueF2O)